# how to validate editable text in the cell table

Tags: gwt

I have cell table which contains the editable `textinputcell`,
see the below image which is of editable `textinputcell`

[image]
i want to validate the columns if its number of colleges then user can enter only number(integer cell) and for name of college user can enter only string(text cell). Is there a way to validate before entering the text into inputcell?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2:

I checked my answer again I i were completely wrong for cells.
For a cell its super easy: Add a `CellPreviewHandler` to your table, that allows only numbers on a certain column.

```
table.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<String> event) {
            if (event.isCellEditing()) {
                int column = event.getColumn();
                String type = event.getNativeEvent().getType();
                if (column == 0 && BrowserEvents.KEYPRESS.equals(type)) {
                    if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57)) {
                        event.setCanceled(true);
                        event.getNativeEvent().stopPropagation();
                        event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your clue..no the above code was not working ..i am adding fieldupdater to get the updated value at the same time if i add onbrowserevent fieldupdater is not working